# Обновление приложения

Tags: json, ios, iphone

Как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении приложения удалились все JSON-файлы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хоть уточните, где они у вас лежат, т.к. при обновлении через стор реально создается новый бандл, и данные из старого переносятся в новый, но при этом темп, кажется, не переносится.

В общем виде, самое простое сохранить в настройках номер версии при предыдущем запуске и проверять его на старте, если он не совпадает - убивать папку с json-ами. Примерно как это делается на проверку первого запуска.

Comment: А есть пример, как это все провернуть с номером версии? А json даже не могу сказать, куда загружаю... Делаю как-то так: NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

Comment: Примера не будет - у меня нет времени писать за вас код, равно как нет и времени разбираться с NSURLSessionDataTask (не довелось его использовать - последний год был на поддержке в основном), хотя подозреваю, что конкретное место, куда сохраняется, определяется таки юзером.